# Updating a form when clicked on update button from another view(using routing) in angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular7

I have a Registration for Html to be submitted and later navigate to another view using routing

EmployeeRegister.html

```
<h4 >Employee Register</h4>
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" #id="ngModel" 
[(ngModel)]="service.formData.id">
<div class="bx--form-item form-group">
<input id="text-input-3" name="fullName" #fullName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.fullName" type="text" class="bx--text-input " placeholder="Full Name*" required>
<div *ngIf ="fullName.touched && fullName.invalid" class="validation-error">This field is required</div>
</div>
 <div class="bx--form-item form-group">
  <input id="text-input-3" name="designation" #designation="ngModel" 
 [(ngModel)]="service.formData.designation" type="text" class="bx--text-input" 
         placeholder="Designation">
  <label for="text-input-3" class="bx--label"></label>
</div>
<div class="bx--form-item form-group">
    <input id="text-input-3" name="empCode" #empCode="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.empCode" type="text" class="bx--text-input" placeholder="EmpCode">
  </div>
  <div class="bx--form-item form-group">
      <input id="text-input-3" name="mobile" #mobile="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.mobile" type="text" class="bx--text-input" placeholder="Mobile Number">
      <label for="text-input-3" class="bx--label"></label>
    </div>
  <div class="bx--form-item form-group">
<button class="bx--btn bx--btn--primary" [disabled]="form.invalid" 
 type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

onclick of submit it navigates to another view displaying employeelist

Here is the EmployeeRegister.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/shared/employee.service';
import { NgForm,FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,FormBuilder } from 
'@angular/forms';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.less']
     })
 export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

   Name=  new FormControl('');
   Designation = new FormControl('');
   EmployeeCode = new FormControl('');
   Mobile = new FormControl('');

    constructor(private service:EmployeeService,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private toastr:ToastrService,
    private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
      }

    /*function to reset form after creating and updating form*/
     resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
       if (form != null)
       form.resetForm();
      this.service.formData = {
        id: null,
        fullName: '',
         designation: '',
         empCode: '',
          mobile: '',
            }
           }
           /* submit the data to be added into database having 'employees' 
           as the data 
            collection array*/
            onSubmit(form: NgForm){
             this.router.navigateByUrl('/EmployeeList');
              let data = Object.assign({},form.value);
              delete data.id;
                 if(form.value.id == null)
                  this.firestore.collection('employees').add(data);
else
this.firestore.doc('employees/'+form.value.id).update(data);
this.resetForm(form);
this.toastr.success('Submitted successfully','Employee Register');
       }

         }
```

EmployeeList.Html-It has a  with edit or update button.

```
 <td><a class="btn" (click)="onEdit(emp)" ><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M7.926 3.38L1.002 9.72V12h2.304l6.926-6.316L7.926 3.38zm.738-.675l2.308 2.304 1.451-1.324-2.308-2.309-1.451 1.329zM.002 9.28L9.439.639a1 1 0 0 1 1.383.03l2.309 2.309a1 1 0 0 1-.034 1.446L3.694 13H.002V9.28zM0 16.013v-1h16v1z"></path></svg></a></td>
```

From this view i want to navigate back to EmployeeRegister view with the data on table displaying in the corresponding field.

i Have a edit button on EmployeeList view invoking a function on typescript as follows

EmployeeList.component.ts

```
onEdit(emp:Employee){
this.service.formData=Object.assign({},emp);
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RegisterEmployee');
 }
```

By this code it navigates to the view but without updating of any data on the EmployeeRegister view.How can i implement this?

Comment: Can you provide a stackBlitz?

Comment: where is RegisterEmployee Comp code?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Have updated question with EmployeeRegister component

Comment: StackBlitz will be more helpful cause it is missing service code etc

Comment: @PrashantPimpale..ok...as suggested here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tocfep

Comment: @HKI345 Your stackblitz is erroring out

Comment: @Ankesh sorry about that!!!...here i have added a git repository of working app https://github.com/HusnaKhanam/MyApplication.git